# Private and public key need to have same algorithm?

Tags: java, rsa, algorithm

The private and the public key from the cert must have the same algorithm, correct?

Yes of course pub / priv are a key pair.
So this code would be legal, to be more flexible (e.g. ECDSA or DSA):

```
PrivateKey privkey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(keyAlias, passphrase);
Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(keyAlias);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(privkey.getAlgorithm()); //before: "RSA"
publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec1);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the private and public key will be generated as a keypair in which they use the algorithm to generate that keypair. so obviously the keys will be mathematically related each other, otherwise it wont.